# yahoo/babel-plugin-react-intl evaluates .native.js file extensions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs, babel-plugin-react-intl

Should the [yahoo/babel-plugin-react-intl](https://github.com/yahoo/babel-plugin-react-intl/) plugin be able to evaluate files that have the extension .native.js in a react-native project?

When I console log the files that are evaluated, all the .jsx and .js files in my project are correctly evaluated but the .native.js are not evaluated at all. These files contain standard JSX and when I change the file extension to .js, they are correctly evaluated. However, due to our current setup, we would like to keep the extension .native.js and not change them to just .js

Does anyone perhaps have an idea how to get this plugin working so that .native.js files will also be evaluated?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that I need to configure Babel to not ignore .native.js files, as explained here in  [this issue](https://github.com/yahoo/babel-plugin-react-intl/issues/102)